# Why would sociolinguists want to study perceptual dialectology?

Tags: sociolinguistics

In other words, how would understanding non-linguists' (or the folks') beliefs about and attitudes towards language help us understand dialect diversity?

Comment: Are you sure that's what the instructor means by "perceptual dialectology"? The nearest sociolinguist that I know works in phonetics, and perception is part of phonetics.

Comment: @user6729: I think he's talking about how dialects are perceived: stuff like the experiments where you're shown two recordings by the same person said in different accents and you're asked to judge who is smarter, more educated, etc. (I forgot what these experiments are called...)

Comment: Attitudes of speakers about how other speakers behave -- particularly how they talk --  are part of how humans sort ourselves out into in- and out-groups. Sociolinguists study, quantify, and analyze minute individual speech differences in great quantity and detail, and correlate them with socioeconomic variables. What's been found is that individual and group variation of practically any linguistic detail is correlated strongly with such variables. In other words, how we talk is who we are, in society, and we can't hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the question of whether your instructor was speaking of auditory perception and dialectology, a study of attitudes regarding language reveals much about attitudes about culture. If people say that dialect of language X is "refined" or some such notion, they probably have a positive attitude towards that culture, and if they say that the language form is "primitive" or some such term, they probably have the opposite attitude. If they just say "Hm, sounds a bit different", then they are probably more neutral. You would want to also survey attitudes about non-linguistic features of the culture. Because people generally like to be like everyone else (there are exceptions), that predicts the direction of language shift. If everybody speaking disparaged dialect X shifts to speaking prestige dialect Y, dialect X will cease to exist, and dialect diversity will be decreased. If people are neutral, diversity will not tend to abate so much.